# Sprite Kit collision detection sprites slow down when near to contact sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have setup the physics bodies correctly, and inside my didBeginContact function I simply remove one of the sprites if it makes contact with the other sprite, but the problem is, my sprite slows down when it is near to the 'enemy' sprite.

Let's call the moving sprite 'sprite 1' and the still sprite 'sprite 2'. When sprite 1 is moving towards sprite 2, it detects the collision even before it is visibly touching sprite 1, why is this?

Comment: You need to post a whole lot more than that, starting with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it by changing the physics body form rectangleOfSize to a circle of radius 1 on each of the sprites.